# Error when making an email sending page in web app, rails. What to put in Routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm learning rails and have started to make an app but in the app have a way to send an email. But when I click on submit it I get an `No route matches [POST] "/path"` error and I have no idea what this means, I haven't put anything in the `routes.rb` file, should I have done?

So the main question is what needs to go into the `routes` file so that the email is sent and I no longer get an error

Also I have it in a file which doesn't have a model, is that bad? Could that be why this doesn't work?

Here is my code.

In Controller:

```
def email
  @current_nav_identifier = :email

  def path
    data = params[:body]
    user = params[:emailadd]
    subject = params[:subject]
    Mailer.mail_method(data,user,subject).deliver
    redirect_to :home
  end
end
```

For Form:

```
= form_tag '/path' do
 Email :
 = text_field_tag 'email', ''
 subject:
 = text_field_tag 'subject', ''
 Body:#{text_area_tag 'body', ''}
 \#{submit_tag "submit",:value => "submit"}
```

Mailer:

```
class InviteMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def mail_method(data,email,subject)
    @body=data
    mail(to: email, subject: subject)
  end
end
```

Do I need to make the page in its own folder? so it has it has its own controller and model?

Have I missed something very simple? Any help will be most welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yea you should put a route in `routes.rb`

```
# routes.rb
post 'path', to: 'SomeController#path'
```

each of these routes defined maps to a particular method defined in the corresponding controller, so

```
# some_controller.rb
def path
  ...
  InviteMailer.mail_method(data,user,subject).deliver
  ...
end
```

Is there a reason you defined the `path` method inside `email` method?

Its ok to have files which have no models associated to it. You can google 'service objects' or 'form objects' which are non-MVC classes that people use in ROR apps to facilitate clean coding.